# RewriteCond folder existence based on subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4

I own multiple domains which I would like to all serve off one host. There are a number of users creating their projects on this host, which should all be routed on a per-subdomain basis. I have a handful of rules I would like to set up in my Apache config that automatically determine the document root, but I do not know how to go about it, or if Apache even allows for such "complex" rewrite rules.

This should be the folder structure:

```
/var/www
| example.org
| - foo
| - - index.html
| - bar
| - - somehiddenfile.txt
| - - public
| - - - index.html
| - www
| - - index.html
| - error.html
```

In this example I want `example.org` and `www.example.org` to be routed to `/var/www/example.org/www`.

`foo.example.org` should be routed to `/var/www/example.org/foo` and `bar.example.org` should be routed to `/var/www/example.org/bar/public`. `foobar.example.org` should always serve `/var/www/example.org/error.html` if it exists, and otherwise route to `/var/www/example.org/www` also.

Now, since I do not want to create new configs every time someone creates a new subdomain (they are generally set up via A wildcards anyways (`*.example.org`)), I hope to be able to make this as automatic as possible.

What I don't know however, is how I can use the subdomain with the `-d` check in my Rewrite conditions. Something like `RewriteCond /var/www/${HTTP_HOST} !-d` I can do, but I haven't found anything about doing the same for a split up host (TLD) and subdomain. Please let me know if this is possible somehow.

Comment: Sounds like you might want [dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html).

Comment: That allows me to use substrings such as `%2` for my virtual document root, but do those also work within rewrite rules/conditions? Although this generally seems like what I want, I don't believe I can do this without rewriting some requests

Answer (score 1):

Because each sub-domain relates to different content, i.e. points at a corresponding DocumentRoot, and has it's own settings e.g. custom 404 documents, what you probably want is to use is "name based" VirtualHost directives (rather than match on the host in the request yourself). See the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/index.html) on VirtualHosts for more infos.

The basic idea is that you have a list of sites (www. foo. bar...), with individual parameters (Name, Alias, DocRoot, ErrorDoc), and you need to generate a sequence of VirtualHost declarations in the apache conf file for each site. The generated file is then placed in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (or somewhere similar, depending on your target OS)

Usually for simple cases, admins just write apache configs by hand. But if you entend beyond a couple of sites, or want to change them regularly and automatically, then the simplest way to do that would be to use a templating system like [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) or [erubis](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/), (or if you are more familiar, do it in bash, python, perl etc, or even Chef, or Ansible, if you want to go the DevOps route!)

I think you may still need to add a Rewrite condition to solve the problem of serving the correct Error.html, but the main problem of `ServerName`, `Alias`, and `DocumentRoot` is solved using a templating system.

If you have a wildcard domain record for `*.example.org` and point it at the server, the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` will do the rest...

Basically the site structure is something like this in yaml;

```
---
sites:
- server_name: www.example.org
  server_alias: example.org
  document_root: "/var/www/example.org/www"
- server_name: foo.example.org
  document_root: "/var/www/example.org/foo"
- server_name: bar.example.org
  document_root: "/var/www/example.org/bar/public"
- server_name: foobar.example.org
  document_root: "/var/www/example.org/foobar"
  custom_error: "/error.html"
```

and you could use a jinja2 template to render that out into apache config files. The template would look something like this;

```
{% for site in sites %}
    <VirtualHost *:80  >
      ServerName {{ site.server_name }}
      {% if is defined site.server_alias %}ServerAlias {{ site.server_alias }}{% end if %}
      DocumentRoot {{ document_root }}

      {% if is defined site.custom_error %}ErrorDocument 404  {{ site.custom_error  }}{% endif %}

      <Directory {{ document_root }} >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
{% endfor %}
```

It would produce a config for the VirtualHosts looking something like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80  >
  ServerName www.example.org
  ServerAlias example.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/www

  <Directory /var/www/example.org/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80  >
  ServerName foo.example.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/foo

  <Directory /var/www/example.org/foo>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80  >
  ServerName bar.example.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/bar/public
  <Directory /var/www/example.org/bar>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80  >
  ServerName foobar.example.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/foobar
  ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.org/error.html
  <Directory /var/www/example.org/bar>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically you can express your requirements in yaml (or json) and use a templating tool to convert that into the required config. For example this tool just takes the j2 file, and the yaml files and renders it out;

https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli

This is basically what tools like ansible and chef were designed to do, and in fact ansible uses jinja2 templates and chef uses erubis. However chef and ansible are both fairly complex and would be useful if you wanted to add other stuff, for example adding a mysql database, or configuring SSL certs, then you might use chef/ansible rather than straight templates...